# Unable to set default NSDateFormatter for RestKit object mapping serialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, nsdateformatter

I'm unable to add a date formatter to the list of `RKValueTransformers` that is utilized when serializing dates because `RKObjectMapping's` initialize function always overrides it.

Basically in my apps `didFinishLaunching` I have the following code:

```
// Survey Mapping Mapping
RKEntityMapping * surveyRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];;
[surveyRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"key", @"version"]];

// Add a request descriptor for Surveys
[sharedManager addRequestDescriptor:
[RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:surveyRequestMapping
                                      objectClass:[Survey class]
                                      rootKeyPath:nil
                                           method:RKRequestMethodAny]];

// Update date format so that we can parse dates properly.
// 2013-11-09 14:51:27 +0000
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z";
[[RKValueTransformer defaultValueTransformer] insertValueTransformer:dateFormatter atIndex:0];
```

Once I commented out the following line my `NSDateFormatter` was used.
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/Code/ObjectMapping/RKObjectMapping.m#L140

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

The code that causes you problems basically means that you need to make a call (vortex some other class needs to make a call) to `RKObjectMapping` before you try to install the formatter. Generally you will have a configuration method which creates your mappings, descriptors and manager and you can configure the formatter at the end of that process.

Comment: I moved the `insertValueTransformer` call to after the section of code where I'm creating my RKEntityMapping and I get the same error. I've updated my question to include my EntityMapping code.